# JW player 7 - Closed caption/subtitle appear in the top of the screen

Tags: subtitle, jwplayer7

JW player 7 - Closed caption/subtitle appears in the top of the screen- only on chrome

Answer (score 0):

After extensive investigation found out having captions backgroundOpacity 0, causing the issue. Updating captions backgroundOpacity to 0.5 will resolve the issue.